# NU1108 error while installing DotLiquid with .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, nuget, dotliquid

I have `ASP.NET Core 2.2` i am trying to install [dotliquid](http://dotliquidmarkup.org/) using nuget

`Install-Package DotLiquid -Version 2.0.298`

but getting error

[image]

Does DotLiquid support .NET Core 2.2 ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Update: Actually, I can reproduce your problem.

It seems to be because your solution or project is also called `DotLiquid`. When I create a new ASP.NET Core 2.2 web application called `DotLiquid`, just as you have in your screenshot, then I also get the cycles error:

Edit: This is apparently [by design](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6754).

[image: Project and solution named the same as the NuGet package]

However, if I create an application with any other name, it installs fine.

#### Original answer

I just created a new ASP.NET Core 2.2 web application, and installed the latest version of `DotLiquid` - version `2.0.314` - and it installed successfully. Try that version instead of `2.0.298`.

Comment: I did not realize the message had a drop down.  Seeing this helped me track down the issue- thank you!